Assign variable a value and copy this value to the clipboard
I believe this is very simple, but I haven't figured it out myself. How is it possible to assign variable a value and copy this value to the clipboard in a really concise way?
That is, something like this
zsh=$(which zsh) | pbcopy

What I have now and what works for me, but is not concise enough is:
zsh=$(which zsh); echo $zsh | pbcopy


This question is similar to: How to pipe output of command to two separate commands and store outputs. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@muru Thank you. This is indeed very close and I would say my question is probably a duplicate. But I haven't figured out how to make it work. I tried, for example, zsh=$(which zsh) | tee >(pbcopy), but it doesn't work.

Do you need the variable, or would putting the value on the clipboard directly be better?

@ChrisDavies I need a variable. That is, what I want is: a) if I use pbaste later, it will paste /bin/zsh, and b) if I type echo $zsh, it will return /bin/zsh

zsh=$(which zsh); pbcopy <<< $zsh is the best I've found so far (after my previous attempt didn't work out so well :) ), but it's really just a minor reshuffling of what you have now.

Given that an assignment to a shell variable and printing to a pipe are two fundamentally different things, it's not really surprising that you need to do two different things to achieve both. So, the question is, why isn't the obvious solution "concise enough"? Are you on some kind if an embedded system where you need to count each byte of your scripts?

Did you see the last code block in the answer there? var=$(command | tee >(sort -n > x.txt) >(sort -u > y.txt) | sort -u)? From there it's easy to reduce to what you want zsh=$(which zsh | tee >( pbcopy))

I somehow thought that you could set the variable using parameter expansion, then output it and pipe it:

echo ${zsh::=$(which zsh)} | pbcopy

but that’s incorrect, the variable is set in a subshell.
muru’s variant based on How to pipe output of command to two separate commands and store outputs is shorter than your existing command and the incorrect command above:
zsh=$(which zsh | tee >(pbcopy))

and can be further shortened using multios:
zsh=$(which zsh >&1 >>(pbcopy))


On my system, it looks like the echo command in the first variant is running in a subshell / sub environment, and therefore the variable isn't available in the parent. That's what I ran into with a similar command I posted and deleted earlier: pbcopy <<< ${zsh::=$(which zsh)}.

Using multios: zsh=$(which zsh >&1 >>(pbcopy)).

You could do:
{pbcopy}<<<${zsh::==zsh}

=cmd is a filename expansion operator, that expands to the path of the first command found in $PATH. Similar to what the which builtin outputs except that it expands to external command paths even if there's also an alias/function/builtin/keyword by the same name (so is more like which -p).
${var::=value} is a zsh parameter expansion operator similar to Bourne's ${var=value} and ${var:=value} except that it sets $var to value unconditionally (whether, the variable is set, empty or otherwise).
<<< is the here-string redirection operator (another zsh extension, that one copied by many other shell). Like Bourne's << here-doc it's a redirection operator that redirects for input on a deleted temporary file. Here the temporary file is filled with the string that follows plus a newline character.
In, pbcopy<<<${var::=value}, the redirection would be done in the child process that eventually executes pbcopy, so the assignment would be lost afterwards.
So here instead, we redirect a command group ({...}) which runs in the current shell process so the assignment is not lost, and that command group runs pbcopy in a child process (which inherits that stdin).
To avoid the newline that <<< adds in case pbcopy (like xclip without -r) doesn't strip it, you could use:
printf %s ${zsh::==zsh} > >(pbcopy)

Though that's not shorter than:
zsh==zsh; printf %s $zsh | pbcopy

